# Can I write a loop procedure in Guile?

Tags: guile

I was trying to write a loop procedure in Guile. I came up with the following:

```
(define loop
  (lambda (predicate callback)
    (when predicate)
      callback
      (loop predicate callback)))
```

But that of course didn't work. The compiler doesn't even start as it seems to not be a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the procedure is designed to do, but it does seem like there is an error in the placement of parentheses. `when` evaluates the condition and executes the following statements if it's true. In the above code `when` doesn't see the statements at all.

Maybe you meant to write this:

```
(define loop
  (lambda (predicate callback)
    (when predicate
      callback
      (loop predicate callback))))
```